# Why Am I getting These Errors? (Assembly x86) Matrix Multiplication

Tags: assembly, matrix, x86, multiplication

So yeah Another Homework problem. But I really thought I nailed it this time.. Anyways I'm getting 4 errors that Doesn't seem to make any sense for me O_O or maybe it's just my blind eye or my pathetic excuse for a code But yeah. I'm getting these errors

```
mp5.s:70: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
mp5.s:77: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
mp5.s:83: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
mp5.s:90: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

The assignment this time Is to make an assembly code to do matrix multiplication. I'll paste my code and highlight lines 70, 77, 83, and 90

I might paste a long bunch of codes but all i need to know is why i'm getting these errors. It should be of the same type I don't know why it's not working...

```
extern  printf

segment .data

test1   db  'M','i','s','m','a','t','c','h',0
test2   db  'h','e','l','l','o','!',0
sout    db  "%s", 10, 0

segment .text

    global  matMul


matMul: 
    enter   12,0

    mov eax,    0
    mov [ebp-04], eax   ;i=0
    mov [ebp-08], eax   ;j=0
    mov [ebp-12], eax   ;k=0

    mov eax,    [ebp+24]
    mov ebx,    [ebp+28]
    cmp eax,    ebx
    je  start

    ;; When The Matrices can't b multiplied It prints out "Mismatch" then exits
    push    test1
    push    sout
    call    printf
    jmp done

;;; start with I loop
start:  
iloop:
    mov eax,    [ebp-04]
    mov ebx,    [ebp+20]
    cmp eax,    ebx ;while i < xrow keep looping
    je  done

    inc eax
    mov [ebp-04], eax   ;increments i++
jloop:  
    ;; j loop starts here
    mov eax,    [ebp-8]
    mov ebx,    [ebp+32]
    cmp eax,    ebx ;while j < ycol keep looping
    je  resetJ

    inc eax
    mov eax,    [ebp-08] ;increments j++
kloop:  
    ;; k loop starts here
    mov eax,    [ebp-12]
    mov ebx,    [ebp+24]
    cmp eax,    ebx ;while k < xcol keep loopinbg
    je  resetK

    ;; operation starts
    mov esi,    [ebp+8] ;address of the matrix 1
    mov edi,    [ebp+12] ;address of matrix 2

    mov eax,    [ebp-04]
    mov ebx,    [ebp-12]
    mov ecx,    [ebp+24]
    **mul   ecx,    eax ;xcol * i**
    add ecx,    ebx ;xcol * i + k
    add esi,    ecx ;esi + shift    now esi have the location for x[col*i+k]

    mov eax,    [ebp-12]
    mov ebx,    [ebp-08]
    mov ecx,    [ebp+32]
    **mul   ecx,    eax ;ycol * k**
    add ecx,    ebx ;ycol * k + j
    add edi,    ecx ;edi + shift    now esi have the location for y[col*k + j]

    mov edx,    [esi]   ;edx <- have the value we need
    mov eax,    [edi]   ;eax <- have the 2nd value we need
    **mul   edx,    eax ;x[xcol * i + k] * y[ycol * 1 + k] = edx**

    mov esi,    [ebp+16] ;esi now have the first location of the 3rd matrix

    mov eax,    [ebp-04]
    mov ebx,    [ebp-08]
    mov ecx,    [ebp+28]
    **mul   ecx,    eax ;yrow * i**
    add ecx,    ebx ;yrow * i + j
    add esi,    ecx ;esi + shift    now esi have the location for z[yrow * i + j]
    mov eax,    [esi]   ;eax <- [esi]

    add eax,    edx ;z[yrow * i + j] + x[xcol * i + k] * y[ycol * k + j] = eax;
    mov [esi],  edx
    ;; operation end

    mov eax,    [ebp-12]
    inc eax
    mov eax,    [ebp-12]    ;increment k++


    jmp kloop       ;k loop
    jmp jloop       ;j loop 
    jmp iloop       ;i loop back to start


resetJ:
    mov eax,    0
    mov [ebp-08], eax
    jmp iloop

resetK:
    mov eax,    0
    mov [ebp-12], eax
    jmp jloop

done:   
    leave
    ret



testing:
    push    test2
    push    sout
    call    printf
    jmp done
```

Line 70, 77, 83, and 90 are the ones inside ** ** I don't know why but I was trying to make them Bold font so it's noticable :( I don't know why It doesn't work either. Anyways this whole code is basically a rewrite of my C matrix multiplication program

Which I'll paste here

```
void mm(int *x, int *y, int *z, int xrow, int xcol, int yrow, int ycol){
  if(xcol == yrow){
    int i,j,k;

    for(i = 0; i < xrow; i++){
      for(j = 0; j < ycol; j++){
    for(k = 0; k < xcol; k++){
      z[yrow * i + j] = z[yrow * i + j] + x[xcol * i + k] * y[ycol * k + j];
    }
      }
    }

  }

  else{
    printf("Size Mismatch. Can't Multiply.\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: I realize you already mentioned that it's homework, but some people browse the questions with homework tags, and if you don't tag it as homework, they may not ever see this question!

Answer (score 2):

`MUL`, unsigned multiply, has the following forms (Intel syntax):

```
MUL r/m8
    AX ← AL∗ r/m8
MUL r/m16 
    DX:AX ← AX ∗ r/m16
MUL r/m32
    EDX:EAX ← EAX ∗ r/m32
MUL r/m64
    RDX:RAX ← RAX ∗ r/m64
```

Comment: Normally you actually want `imul reg, reg/mem` (or `imul reg, r/m, imm`)  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul, when you don't need or want the high-half result.

Answer (score 1):

It was a while since I coded 80x86 assembler, but doesn't the MUL opcode take just one operand, and implicitly use the accumulator (EAX) as one of the terms, and EAX+EDX to store the results? (Of course, back when I was coding in assembly, it was just plain old AX and DX: none of these fancy-shmancy 32 or 64 bit stuff for us!)

Comment: Just check my professors Notes and You may be right :'( I feel so stupid atm. Anyways I'll try it the way he does it and I'll tell you how that goes

Comment: Oh yeah THat's the problem Thanks a lot for the quick reply It's very much appreciated. I think you just saved 8% of my grade :)